# Do all magsafe power ports have the same form factor?

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

I have a MacBook6,1 with a 60W magsafe power adapter.  The cord on the adapter got chewed up by my rabbit (she's fine) and I would like very much to replace it.  But I really don't want to spend the $79 on the Apple Store!

I've seen magsafe adapters for as low as $27 elsewhere, but the connectors look different than mine.

This link, from Amazon, also 60W, claims to work for MacBooks (all of them, or some of them?), but is much less expensive: http://amzn.to/f3Xsc7

Inspecting the connector in the picture, the only difference I can see is mine is "L" shaped and the the one in the picture plugs straight in perpendicularly.  If the connectors have the same form factor and the power specs are the same, it seems that I could get away with the cheaper one.

So, will all magsafe adapters plug into my macbook and charge it?

Comment: If you're considering buying the unit you linked to, read the reviews first.

Comment: With regard to wattage, you can use the wattage that came with any given Macbook or higher. (i.e. if your notebook was a MBA that came with a 45 watt adapter, you could use a 45, 60, or 80. If it was a 17" MBP that came with an 80 watt, only an 80 watt will do.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - the computer side of things is the same, but the newer cord layout is needed for Airs or when the space around the port is restricted.

The 'L-shaped' MagSafe adapters were just a newer design which meant the cable went backwards instead of outwards.  They should fit just fine and I've used one or two third-party ones in the past.  Just as long as you pick the right power-output you should be fine.  Here's a [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/04/22/apple-quietly-updates-design-of-magsafe-power-adapter/) article on the matter

Comment: Yup.  Make sure the wattage is the same and you'll be fine.  They both fit.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a 2007 MacBook MagSafe adapter on my 2010 MacBook Pro with no problems. They are smart enough to switch voltages depending on the model.

I'd still try and find the right one for your machine though just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

The design was changed to prevent strain on the cables. They can be used interchangeably.

85 watt adapters can be used on any portable.
60 watt adapters the 13' MB, MBP, MBAirs and 11' Airs
45 watt adapters is for the MBAirs

Some units will work on lower voltages but usually won't charge the battery and if the unit is dead without a charge it won't start.